# Improve google page speed score for React Application through gzip compression on node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, gzip

I'm building a react application that uses `webpack` which is generating a `bundle.js` of around `2 MB!` Hence, the website's rating on `Google Page Speed` is pretty low. I would like to improve this for which I minified all images, javascript, css files. The rating improved but is still poor.

I see `"Enable compression"` as the top suggestion in the google page speed insights for which I tried to integrate `g-zip compression`. Through this I could generate a compressed `bundle.min.gz` but when I include this in my `index.html`, the browser returns an `"Uncaught Syntax Error"` and nothing works

I assume that I'm missing something in setting up the server for sending `g-zip compressed` content. I'm pretty new at this. I would appreciate any help in improving page speed / enabling compression for a react application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I posted an answer, but you can not require javascript file with gz extension. Just rename it bundle.min.js.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected that. Used this as reference and it worked for me. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nginx in front of your app. It might sounds like overhead, but it is totally common practice. Nginx provide security, logs, cache, gzip, https and much more out of the box. In your nginx config add this configuration:

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript 
application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss 
text/javascript;
```

In this case dont bother with any other configs (like webpack).